# In given random varaible $ X$ ~ $Geo(p)$ what is E(X=x)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

In given random varaible $ X$ ~ $Geo(p)$  what is E(X=x)?
(I know that E(X)=$\frac{1}{p})$.

Comment: There are tons of questions here asking the same thing. Have you tried searching and more importantly, what have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by $E(X=x)$?

Comment: And WP is not an option because?

Comment: @StubbornAtom , if X ~ Geo(p) , so what is E(X | X=x) ?

Comment: "if X ~ Geo(p) , so what is E(X | X=x) ?" ?? For **every** X, E(X|X=x)=x. Sorry but it is difficult to understand what is blocking you (apart from, perhaps, having  no idea about what the symbols you are using, actually mean).

Comment: We seem to have a case of homework outsourcing here. Three questions so far, all terrible, with no personal input whatsoever. OP: Please change your modus operandi.

Comment: Answer accepted 1 minute after being posted. Did you understand anything at all from it?

Comment: @Did How can i understand how a random variable split?

Comment: "How can i understand how a random variable split?" What? Are you somewhat obliquely admitting that you understand nothing from the answer below? Why accept it, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by $X=x$ you mean indicator $\Bbb{1}(X=x)$, then the answer is merely
$$\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{1}(X=x)) = \Bbb{P}(X=x)$$
For natural $x$ the last probability is $p^{x - 1}(1-p)$ or $p^x$ depending on how you define $Geo(p)$ distribution.

Comment: if X ~ Geo(p) , so what is E(X | X=x) ?

Comment: The question you ask in the comment differs from the one you asked in the post. It still unclear what exactly do you mean. The expectation of the indicator is just a probability and I elaborated it above. The conditional expectation you ask about is just $x$ (what is the expected value of X if we know that X equals to x? Obviously, x).